# Google Places API - Fetch place ID using the share link

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to work on a feature where the user enters the share link of a place (ex. https://goo.gl/maps/T7mAjUT4FGaxxxxxx) and they get the google place ID (ex. ChIJBcCC4G4XHxURmxxxxxxxxxx)

I was working on getting the name from the share link, then searching for the name, and then getting the google ID from the first result (which is clearly a bad approach)

```
`
<Button
  title={"Test"}
  onPress={async () => {
    const url = "https://goo.gl/maps/T7mAjUT4FGaTWFox9";

    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    console.log(extractNameFromURL(res.url));
  }}
/>`
```

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to extract place details from the full URL   `https://www.google.com/maps/place/East+village/@33.8689194,35.5000217,15.23z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x151f170eb0790869:0xd3a5ae729078d4ac!8m2!3d33.8728688!4d35.5158373!16s%2Fg%2F11cnc90ywj?entry=tts&shorturl=1`

Then use Google Geocoding API to extract place information including Place ID - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#geocoding-request-and-response-latitudelongitude-lookup